# traefik, bare-metal kubernetes : secret doesnt exist

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am using kubernetes on bare-metal (v1.10.2) and latest traefik (v1.6.2) as ingress. I am seeing following issue when I want to enable traefik to route to a httpS service.

`Error configuring TLS for ingress default/cheese: secret default/traefik-cert does not exist`

The secret exists ! why does it report that it doesnt ?

On the basis of comment: secret is inaccessible from traefik service account. But I dont understand why.

Details as follows:

```
kubectl get secret dex-tls -oyaml --as gem-lb-traefik
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "dex-tls" is forbidden: User "gem-lb-traefik" cannot get secrets in the namespace "default"
$ kubectl describe clusterrolebinding gem-lb-traefik
Name:         gem-lb-traefik
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  gem-lb-traefik
Subjects:
  Kind            Name            Namespace
  ----            ----            ---------
  ServiceAccount  gem-lb-traefik  default
$ kubectl describe clusterrole gem-lb-traefik
Name:         gem-lb-traefik
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources             Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------             -----------------  --------------  -----
  endpoints             []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  secrets               []                 []              [get list watch]
  services              []                 []              [get list watch]
  ingresses.extensions  []                 []              [get list watch]
```

I still dont understand why I am getting error of secret inaccessibility from the service account

Comment: Maybe Traefik doesn't have permissions to access that secret, ow did you deploy Traefik? Are your kubernetes cluster using RBAC?

Comment: ```kubectl get secret dex-tls --as gem-lb-traefik
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "dex-tls" is forbidden: User "gem-lb-traefik" cannot get secrets in the namespace "default"
``` thanks. I see that it cannot get secrets. Let me see !

Comment: Here is official documentation for deploying with RBAC: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#role-based-access-control-configuration-kubernetes-16-only

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in this case, you cannot check the access to the secret using `--as gem-lb-traefik` key because it tries to run the command as **user** `gem-lb-traefik`, but you have no such user, you only have **ServiceAccount** with **ClusterRole** `gem-lb-traefik`. Moreover, using `--as <user>` key with any nonexistent user provides an error similar to yours:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "<secretname>" is forbidden: User "<user>" cannot get secrets in the namespace "<namespace>"
```

So, as @Ignacio Millán mentioned, you need to check your settings for Traefik and fix them according to the official [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#role-based-access-control-configuration-kubernetes-16-only). Possibly, you missed your ServiceAccount in Traefik DaemonSet description. Also, you need to check if Traefik DaemonSet is located in the same namespace as ServiceAccount for which you use ClusterRoleBinding.

Comment: thanks for the info. I discussed with one of the traefik devs on slack. have created an issue https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3402. Btw, I did check that service account with which the traefik pod is mounted, has sufficient access to see the secrets. I dont know what the issue is.